# How to model a pyramid of specific lengths for each edge?

Tags: modeling, edges

I am trying to model a triangular based pyramid and have a unique length for each edge. I am new to blender and finding it difficult.

The pyramid I am trying to model has a base of edges length 53 / 27 / 31 cm and then the edges reaching up have lengths of length 43 / 48 / 51 cm

any help would be great!

Comment: You can use this formula: https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath424/kmath424.htm to find the volume and this formula to find the area of the base https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula Wtih that you'll have the height of the tetrahedron, which solves the problem. Based on this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910855/how-to-find-the-height-of-an-irregular-triangular-pyramid

Comment: And this: https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1329962711

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

1. Enable Edge Length measurement:

[image]

2. Create a regular cone of 3 vertices and enter edit mode, now when you move a vertex you will see the length of each segment as you move:
   [image]

I hope this helps.